# How to embed widget apk with the application widget

Tags: android

I have an app and its widget. What must I do, that I can install one thing. And not install the app and the widget. Install app and the widget automatically get installed.

jibysthomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to include a widget with your app you need to set up your manifest appropriately.  Check out the documentation here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

If it's not working or your having a specific problem, post that question.

Comment: Then where i have to write the widget class and the other things for widgets?

Comment: @jibysthomas You can add the class to your src folder the same way you do for Activities.  You add your xml to the res/layout folder as you do for other layouts.  etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add receiver in manifest and appwidgetprovider.java in src